# iPad bug landscape left different from landscape right

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, delegates

Here is my problem:

in my iPad `Split View Controller` i have the detail full of textfields, from the navigationBar to the end of the view.
Now i'm using delegates to animate the view in order to let the user write without having the keyboard hiding the textFields.
This is the code in `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    //CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

        if (detail) // iPad
            viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
        else // iPhone
            viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
        if(detail)
            viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
        else
            viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

and it works perfectly on `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, but on`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` the last 2 textFields are not animated and i can't figure out why!

Before any comments YES i ctrl-dragged the delegate from each textFields and i'm saying than on `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` i have no problem. Just if i change orientation only the last 2 does not move.

Actually i wanted to know if any of you had the same problem and if you managed to solve or maybe it's just a bug or else my code in bugged :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the *textFieldRect* sizes , in iOS 7 the height and width value will swap when device is in landscape mode , so you need to change them on your formula.